# Does react.js play nice with jQuery/UI components

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, reactjs

React (and Om for cljs) looks extremely appealing but I imagine it is probably not possible to use non-React components e.g. jQuery and jQueryUI ones together with React code on the same page/app.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: React works within a _virtual_ DOM, so it isn't very useful to manipulate objects on the _actual_ DOM in parallel. In this way, jQuery and others don't play too well with React. However, there are ways of referencing the actual DOM, through `getDOMNode()`, etc that will allow you to integrate your existing jQuery plugins to work with React. See http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html for more info.

Answer (score 46):

Yes, **react can play well** with your libraries.

Check out the documentation:[Integrating with Other Libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)

Comment: While it *can* play well, you have to be careful, because if your other library happens to modify some part of react-controlled HTML, your app will stop working. You have been warned.

Comment: Additionally, check out [this answer, where I am showing an approach how to use jQuery UI with ReactJS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40350880/1333836).

Comment: @mik01aj Thanks for the warning :)

Comment: @jmingov Both links are dead.