# Javascript framework for search friendly websites

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have used JQuery + JQueryUI for some projects including an ERP project but sometimes during the project developers would complain that the simple framework I have created is incapable and sometimes messy. I have a new project which is a public eCommerce website (i.e. a mini ebay) which needs to be search friendly.

I am looking for a properly designed framework. Initially I liked AngularJS but it seems I will have problem finding UI components (like those I used in JQueryUI). Is there an AngularJS like (or any framework that provides properly designed and manageable code structure) that supports JQueryUI?

I am aware that it is possible to use AngularJS with JQueryUI but the code seems to be very messy and difficult to produce/understand for typical LAMP developers.

Oh, and freeware is very much preferred (otherwise ExtJS would be fine I guess).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might get closed as opinion based, but you should give [React.js](http://facebook.github.io/react/) a try. React supports [server side rendering](http://reactjsnews.com/isomorphic-javascript-with-react-node/) (great for SEO) and  [plays well with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030023/does-react-js-play-nice-with-jquery-ui-components). I'm using it for a project right now that leverages jQuery UI and I'm having a great time!